# How to reference an attribute from one class using another class

Tags: python-3.x, class, instantiation

Here is my code

```
import random

class Player_Character:
    def __init__(self, hp, maxhp, ac, THAC0):
        self.hp = int(hp)
        self.maxhp = int(maxhp)
        self.ac = int(ac)
        self.THAC0 = int(THAC0)
    def attack(goblin):
        Player_Character_Damage = random.randint(1,10)
        goblin.hp -= Player_Character_Damage
        if (goblin.hp <= 0):
            print("congratulations you killed the goblin")
            del goblin

class goblin:
    def __init__(self, hp, maxhp, ac, THAC0):
        self.hp = int(hp)
        self.maxhp = int(maxhp)
        self.ac = int(ac)
        self.THAC0 = int(THAC0)
    def attack(Player_Character):
        goblin_damage = random.randint(1,4)
        Player_Character.hp -= goblin_damage
        if (Player_Character.hp <= 0):
            print("oh dear you have died")
            del Player_Character


Player_Character(10, 20, 10, 15)
goblin(5, 10, 8, 18)

Player_Character.attack(goblin)
```

I expect Player_Character.attack(goblin) to do 1-10 damage to the goblin (probably killing it) but instead I get an error: `AttributeError: type object 'goblin' has no attribute 'hp'`... obviously I created the class with a 'hp' attribute and am now confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to instantiate objects

as @ShadowRanger explained in the comments, I should have mentioned that I added self to functions

```py
import random

class Player_Character:
    def __init__(self, hp, maxhp, ac, THAC0):
        self.hp = int(hp)
        self.maxhp = int(maxhp)
        self.ac = int(ac)
        self.THAC0 = int(THAC0)
    def attack(self, goblin):
        Player_Character_Damage = random.randint(1,10)
        goblin.hp -= Player_Character_Damage
        if (goblin.hp <= 0):
            print("congratulations you killed the goblin")
            del goblin

class goblin:
    def __init__(self, hp, maxhp, ac, THAC0):
        self.hp = int(hp)
        self.maxhp = int(maxhp)
        self.ac = int(ac)
        self.THAC0 = int(THAC0)
    def attack(self, Player_Character):
        goblin_damage = random.randint(1,4)
        Player_Character.hp -= goblin_damage
        if (Player_Character.hp <= 0):
            print("oh dear you have died")
            del Player_Character


p = Player_Character(10, 20, 10, 15)
g = goblin(5, 10, 8, 18)


p.attack(g)
```

also @ShadowRanger mentioned that del does not work as intended, you can use it outside to delete instances.

```py
p = Player_Character(10, 20, 10, 15)
g = goblin(5, 10, 8, 18)

p.attack(g)

if(g.hp <= 0):
    print("congratulations you killed the goblin")
    del g
```

Comment: When I do that it returns this: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Hezekiah\PycharmProjects\OOP\Code it Yourself RPG.py", line 34, in <module>
    p.attack(g)
TypeError: attack() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Comment: @HezekiahBodine: You didn't notice (not your fault, @can didn't mention it) that they added a `self` parameter to each of your instance methods; you need that `self` parameter for this (and all instance methods) to work. In this specific case, you don't actually use `self` (apparently all goblins do damage exactly the same way in all cases), so you could drop `self` and decorate with `@staticmethod` and it would work, but if you want to use, say, their `THAC0` to determine if they hit, you'd need `self.THAC0` to access it.

Comment: Side-note: With proper instances, I should note that `del` doesn't do what the OP thinks it does. As written, it's totally pointless (it's implicitly `del`ed when the method returns immediately after that line), as unbinding the local reference has no effect on `p` or `g` outside the function.

Comment: issue resolved thank you all for contributing.